# Object.constructor===Object.constructor.constructor // why?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

stated here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function the constructor property of an instance of a function object "specifies the function that creates an object's prototype". This is confusing, so **Object.constructor** is "the function that creates an object's prototype"? What object is "an object" exactly?

I'm trying to understand why is Object.constructor's constructor property itself?

as such: Object.constructor===Object.constructor.constructor // why?

Edit: i find T.J. Crowder's answer good but the phrasing of his words is pretty vague (making it hard to understand at first read, at least for me). Here's the rephrased answer:

1) **Object** is an instance of **Function**

2) **Object** does not have a property called **constructor** so when we call **Object.constructor**, it actually gives us **Object.[[prototype]].constructor** (aka **Object.__*proto*__.constructor**).

3) **Object.constructor** (aka **Object.__*proto*__.constructor**) is an instance of **Function**.

4) Since both **Object** and **Object.constructor** (aka **Object.__*proto*__.constructor**) are instances of **Function** therefore they both have a **__*proto*__** property which refer to the same object. In other words **Object.__*proto*__ === Object.constructor.__*proto*__** (aka **Object.__*proto*__.constructor._*proto*_**)

5) The line **Object.constructor===Object.constructor.constructor** is actually equal to the line **Object.__*proto*__.constructor===Object.constructor.__*proto*__.constructor**

6) combining steps 4 and 5 give us **Object.constructor===Object.constructor.constructor**

7) goto step 4)

Comment: http://joost.zeekat.nl/constructors-considered-mildly-confusing.html

Comment: A nice diagram of JS object layout is here.http://www.mollypages.org/tutorials/js.mp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `Object` is a `Function`, and the `Function` constructor is a `Function`, so its constructor is itself.

An "object" is the fundamental building block of object-oriented programming. `Object`, in JavaScript, is a *constructor function* (like `Date`, or `RegExp`). Its job is to initialize new instances of objects created by the interpreter via the `new` keyword.

This may be off-topic, or not, since you're asking about constructors:

Any function in JavaScript can be a constructor function; it's purely a matter of how you use it. Consider:

```
function Foo() {
}
```

If I call that like this:

```
var f = Foo();
```

...it's just a boring old function, and `f` receives `undefined` (since `Foo` doesn't return anything). But if I call it like this:

```
var f = new Foo();
```

...I'm using it as a *constructor* function and something more interesting happens:

1. The interpreter creates a new, blank object.
2. The interpreter sets the new object's underlying prototype to be `Foo.prototype`.
3. The interpreter calls `Foo` in a way that makes `this` refer to the new object.
4. When `Foo` completes, if `Foo` doesn't return a value (or doesn't return an object), the result of the `new` expression is the object created in step 1. (If `Foo` returns an object, that object is used instead; that's an advanced thing most people don't have to do.)

Answer (score 5):

JavaScript Object Layout

[image]

Comment: Nice diagram. Note that `__proto__` is non-standard and not supported by all implementations. The concept is always there, but not the symbol. (The spec calls it `[[Prototype]]` and doesn't make it accessible programmatically except via the brand-new function `Object.getPrototypeOf` in ECMAScript5.)