# why **(Object.__proto__ instanceof Function)** === false?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

why does **Object._*proto*_ instanceof Function** gives me false?

```
alert(Object.__proto__ ); //  clearly Object.__proto__ is a function right?
alert(typeof Object.__proto__); // clearly Object.__proto__ is a function right?
alert(Object.__proto__ instanceof Function); // !
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not all functions are created via the `Function` constructor. `instanceof` checks specifically to see if the given item was created by *that specific function*.

You get a similar effect in browser environments when dealing with multiple windows. I mean, if you have function `foo` in window A:

```
function foo(arg) {
    if (arg instanceof Array) {
        // It's an array, do something
    }
}
```

...and you have code in *another window* B that calls it:

```
opener.foo([]);
```

...then you'd expect `foo` to realize that `arg` is an array, right? But it doesn't, because although `arg` *is* an array, it wasn't created by the `Array` constructor in the window that `foo` is in.

More about figuring out what things are here: [*Say what?*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/09/say-what.html)

If you're fascinated by this stuff (as you seem to be), there's nothing quite like reading [the specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm). Yes, the prose is...dry...and the terminology is....dense...but it gets more and more interesting as you learn more and more about the underlying workings.

---

**Off-topic**: Beware that `__proto__` is non-standard and not supported by all JavaScript implementations.

Comment: +1 - That "Say what?" link is a good resource. Nice and succinct.

Comment: Haha and I just realized it's your blog. Cheers to you!

Comment: @McStretch: LOL! Hmmm, maybe I should label with a disclaimer or something... Enh, no complaints so far. ;)

Comment: Haha no it's very useful, I don't think you should need a disclaimer when you're trying to help.

Comment: @T.K. Crowder when you say "You don't actually need multiple windows for this to come up, but that's the most common way in browser apps. You have to be doing esoteric things for it to come up otherwise." what esoteric ways are you referring to?

Comment: @T.K. Crowder Heys i've just read the article btw i think you may need to address on performance issues with duck. Its not uncommon to have 40 properties on a single object so basically everytime i run my duck-check-function i have to duck-check the amount of properties that i use within the function? everytime? (i'm not saying that's wrong, im just saying perhaps you wanted to address this issue in your blog post)

Comment: @Pacerier: (It's "T.J.") I remember that I had an example when I wrote the article, but I have to admit I don't immediately remember it. It had to do with unusual construction patterns. (But you can get the same effect with shadowing -- e.g., defining a new `Date` symbol -- but that wasn't the example I had in mind.) Re duck typing: You'd only have to do that if the actual function *used* all 40 properties. I can't remember the last time I had to check more than, say, five. But I see your point.

Answer (score 3):

To end with the mystery:

What exactly is `Object.__proto__`?

- It is simply a reference to the `Function.prototype` object.

  ```
  Object.__proto__ === Function.prototype; // true
  ```

The [`Object`](http://es5.github.com/#x15.2.2) constructor as *almost* all of the built-in and user defined functions, inherit from `Function.prototype`.

This object (`Function.prototype`) is [described in the specification](http://es5.github.com/#x15.3.4) to be a *Function object*,  but obviously, **an object can't inherit from itself**, and that's why it inherits from `Object.protoype` instead.

Your test:

```
Object.__proto__ instanceof Function;   // false, which is equivalent to:
Function.prototype instanceof Function; // false
```

Is simply telling us that the `Function.prototype` object *is not* on the *prototype chain* of `Function.prototype` itself:

```
Function.prototype.isPrototypeOf(Function.prototype); // false, equivalent to:
Object.prototype.isPrototypeOf.call(Function.prototype, Function.prototype);
```

As I told before, [in the specification](http://es5.github.com/#x15.3.4) this object described with the following characteristics, if you are interested:

- It is a function object (implements the [`[[Call]]`](http://es5.github.com/#x15.3.4) internal method).

  ```
  typeof Function.prototype; // "function"
  ```
- The value of its `[[Class]]` internal property is `"Function"`.

  ```
  Object.prototype.toString.call(Function.prototype); // "[object Function]"
  ```
- The value of its `[[Prototype]]` internal property points to `Object.prototype` (as you know now).

  ```
  Object.prototype.isPrototypeOf(Function.prototype); // true
  ```
- Can be called with any number of arguments.
- It always returns the `undefined` value.
- Its `length` property is `0`.
- The initial value of its `[[Extensible]]` internal property is `true`.

Answer (score 2):

```
alert(Object.__proto__ ); //  clearly Object.__proto__ is a function right?
alert(typeof Object.__proto__); // clearly Object.__proto__ is a function right?
alert(Object.__proto__ instanceof Function); // !
```

Exactly, it is a function. However, it is not a function ***object***. That's why instanceof returns false. You can read all about instanceof [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/instanceof).

Comment: *"However, it is not a function object."* It may well be a function object (in fact, it probably is). Just not one created via that specific `Function` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

the image in this post will help you understand the Function vs Object relation

[JavaScript Object Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963547/object-constructor-object-constructor-constructor-why)